# How do I get devise 2.2.3 to accept auto-geneated password for rails 3.2.13 app

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am attempting to create a rails 3.2.13 app where when the user is created a password is auto generated for that user. Right now I am using a before_validate to generate and assign the password to the password and password_confirmation fields on the user object before it is creates but devise still complains that the password is still blank.

What is the best approach to get devise to accept the password that I have generated for my user object? It would be nice to be able to do this without having to overwriting the internal validation if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known what you are doing wrong... Tried quickly here and everything turned out ok.

Here is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  before_validation :set_user_password

  def set_user_password
    @password = Devise.friendly_token
  end 
end
```

I didn't even had to set password_confirmation just password and it saved without errors at the rails console.

Comment: I will have to look up what Devise.friendly_token does. It also would have helped if I actually pasted my code. Sorry about that. I did find one issue after I took another look at my code just now which is I can see what the problem is. The issue is that I was calling before_validate as opposed to before_validation. Once I ran my tests, everything passed. Very interesting that all you had to do was set an @password variable. That's a much cleaner approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why I am not able to hit a new line by hitting enter. Sorry for the long paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

The previous solution is awesome. But you can not reset your password. set_user_password should only execute when creating account.

```
before_validation :set_user_password, :on => :create
def set_user_password
    @password = Devise.friendly_token
end
```